# multi parameter data subscription in ssrs only working with one value

Tags: reporting-services

I've started using SSRS for 6 month and trying to setup a data driven report where the parameter in the report may contain multiple values (customer numbers).

Ive tried to follow the guideline from microsoft:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3b0f1620-a7ac-4edd-a577-4beef4bddb14/forum-faq-how-to-configure-a-data-driven-subscription-which-get-multivalue-parameters-from-one?forum=sqlreportingservices#3b0f1620-a7ac-4edd-a577-4beef4bddb14

The parameter in the report is setup following the guideline:

1. uncheck “Allow multiple values” option for the parameter
2. check "none" on available values
3. check "none" on default values

The dataset properties for the parameter are setup by adding a filter:

CustomerKey in split(Parameters!Customer.Value, ",")

The report is working fine when there is only one customer in the subscription table but report is empty when the number of customer are more than one.

The data set of the report is not changed. The query of the data subscription is retrieving the data from the SQL table where I have stored the emails and customer number are related. The data tables looks like this:

[image: ReportSubscription]

The tabel is formatted in this way:

[image]

The query in the subscription using the table looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Table_Archive].[dbo].[ReportSubscription]
where ReportName='CustomerOrder' and Schedule='Every day'
```

The data retreived to be used in the report is defined by the following query:

```
select 
CustomerLabel AS CustomerLabel
, CustomerKey AS CustomerKey
, SalesItemKey AS SalesItemKey
, SalesItemName AS SalesItemName
, SalesOrderDetailNumberKey
From factview.SalesOrder 
where  CustomerKey in (@Customer)
```

I've tried multiple solution on how to specify the customer number in the table (',';"," etc) but without success. I'm quite uncertain if the approach that i'm trying will ever work and i'm having difficulties in finding any good suggestions, hence this post.

Comment: When you run the query for the subscription, are the customer IDs in this format: `A,B,C`?

Comment: The data is stores in the table cell as a,b,c

Comment: Everything you described sounds correct. Other than making sure CustomerKey is surrounded by a `CStr` function in your filter, I don't see any red flags. In order to find the problem, I think we would need more specifics of the data and settings you're using. Also just to confirm, the query returns one row, right?

Comment: I solved it by using a different approach: _https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/tag/ssrs/_

Comment: The table containing the data to be used in the parameter is setup as a data set for the parameter and then is the split function used in the parameter in the data set for the report